# Using multiple Python versions with Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am using [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) installers and have Python 2 installed. I however, do want to use both Python 2 and 3 interchangeably in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter). I read through the instructions provided in *[Installing the IPython kernel](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)*.

Does it mean that I do not need to install Python 3, just the kernel to start using both Python 2 and 3 in Jupyter?

Comment: If you want to use a Python 3 kernel, you need to install Python 3.

Comment: Yep, you'll need both installed. Conda makes it easy to create a Python 3 env, however: `conda create -n py3 python=3`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am trying it right now. Hope it is as easy as you guys make it sound :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) makes it a breeze. The [full documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) should guide to manage both Python 3 and Python 2.